# problema al visualizar un array en una tabla Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Bien gracias a los compañeros del foro he conseguido hacer el join para obtener los datos en un array como queria, este es el metodo del controlador:

```
public function solicitudes()
    {
        $vacations =  \DB::table('vacations')
            ->select('workers.name','vacations.type','vacations.date_from','vacations.date_to','vacations.observations','vacations.aceptado')
            ->join('workers','workers.id','=','vacations.worker_id')
            ->where(['vacations.aceptado' => '0']);
        //dd($vacations);
        return view('vacation.showvac')->with('vacations', $vacations->get());              
 }
```

con el dd esto me devuelve:

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => {#224 ▼
    +"name": "David Pazo"
    +"type": "vacacion"
    +"date_from": "1970-01-01"
    +"date_to": null
    +"observations": "asd"
    +"aceptado": 0
  }
  1 => {#225 ▶}
  2 => {#226 ▶}
  3 => {#227 ▶}
  4 => {#228 ▶}
  5 => {#229 ▶}
  6 => {#230 ▶}
  7 => {#231 ▶}
  8 => {#232 ▶}
  9 => {#233 ▶}
]
```

lo cual esta genial, pero cuando llego a la vista de blade, tengo un if, para comprobar si hay datos o no y no me devuelve datos ninguno:

```
@if(count($vacations) > 0)
                                <h2 class="text-center">No hay solicitudes pendientes</h2>
                            @else
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered scrolling-dataTable">
                            <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                <th>Fecha inicio</th>
                                <th>Fecha fin</th>
                                <th>Observaciones</th>
                                <th>Pendiente</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            @foreach ($vacations as $vacation => $array)
                                <tr>
                                    {{$vacation}}

                                    @foreach ($array as $item)

                                    <td>{{$item['name']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$item['type']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$item['date_from']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$item['date_to']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$item['observations']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$item['aceptado']}}</td>
```

y ya me tiene loco, porque todo los ejemplos que vi lo hacen asi, pero a mi no me llegan los datos al if de la vista desde el controlador, agradeceria cualquier ayudita, un saludo comunidad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function solicitudes()
    {
        $vacations =  \DB::table('vacations')
            ->select('workers.name','vacations.type','vacations.date_from','vacations.date_to','vacations.observations','vacations.aceptado')
            ->join('workers','workers.id','=','vacations.worker_id')
            ->where(['vacations.aceptado' => '0'])
            ->get();

        return view('vacation.showvac', ['vacations' => $vacations]);              
 }
```

Y en la vista

```
@foreach ($vacations as $vacation)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $vacation->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->date_from }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->date_to }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->observations }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->aceptado }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Gracias!!!! Funciono!!! por unos corchetes manda narices, muchisimas gracias a todos de verdad, con una comunidad asi da gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo uso de esta manera:

```html
@foreach ($vacations as $vacation)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $vacation->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->date_from }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->date_to }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->observations }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vacation->aceptado }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: asi es como lo tenia al principio pero los datos parece ser que no llegan del controlador a la vista, o por lo menos al if que esta antes no llega dato alguno, me imagino que el problema esta en la comunicacion no como imprimo el array porque no tiene mucha ciencia... gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: ¿Si quitas el IF te devuelven datos?

Comment: El método get, no me agrada en tu controlador, intenta con `return view('vacation.showvac')->with('vacations', $vacations)` o `return view('vacation.showvac', compact('vacations'))`

Comment: Aun quitando el If, no devuelve datos ningunos a la vista, Luis he probado lo que me has dicho y basicamente viene a ser lo mismo la vista no recibe datos, de hecho el if lo puse despues para comprobar si llegaban los datos. si quito el if, simplemente carga la tabla sin datos.